# How to get File when having path of its store location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, file-upload

I have the following issue: I have a frontend where I can post data that contains strings and an image file to my backend, but this function is only available for the user, when he is logged in. But when he is not logged in and tries to send this request he will get an error and has the opportunity to login. Therefore I want to save the current data, that he wants to post and already wrote to the inputs, in order to parse the data in the input fields, when gets back to the page where he can post the data. Currently I am saving the data in the localStorage and that works completely fine, but I have the problem, that of course I can't (it would be possible, but I think localstorage is not a good way to save a file in it) and won't save the file in the localstorage. So my question is how I can get the file from the users pc when having the path of the file (in my case stored in the localstorage).

Comment: A file input won't give you the actual users file path and you can't programmatically set a file input. If not logged in why are they able to see this form? Not letting them use the form makes the flow a lot simpler

Comment: I can get the file path with a filereader, so actually I have it. For my backend logic its easier to do it like that, because when I am doing it this way, I only have to add an authorize annotation above the post method. If I would make it like you suggest, I would have to ask my backend everytime if the accesstoken is valid to get access to this page

Comment: Fine but it's not a good user experience to be provided a form , fill it out and then get told you need to sign in. Less friction having them sign in first

Comment: Yea, but how should I implement this? Is it the right way to call a method in the backend, that accepts an accesstoken and tells me if I am signed in?

Comment: That sounds reasonable...sure